# Type checking with Prolog

Tags: types, prolog, typechecking

I tried to code a type checker with Prolog, but i'm a noob with Prolog, my rule doesn't work, and I don't understand why?

(I already have defined facts for `bool` etc.)

types are lists, for example `int * int -> int` is `[int,int,int]` so the type of "add" is `lastOf([int,int,int])`

my rule: `if e1:bool, if e2:t and if e3:t, so (if e1 e2 e3):t`

my Prolog rule:

```
type( iF(Cond, Cons, Alter), Env, Y) :- 
    type( Cond, Env, T1) , 
    type( Cons, Env, T2), 
    type( Alter, Env, T2), 
    lastOf( X, T1), 
    X == bool, 
    lastOf( Y, T2).
```

Comment: @GuyCoder this is MY rule...

Comment: What would you expect to happen? Where is the code for `lastof/2`? Where are the clauses for the recursion? Currently you could only check an infinite tree of `iF(_,_,_)` expressions because you only defined `type/3` for `iF`.

Comment: Would you expect `lastOf(bool, T1)` to work? That's essentially what you have there. Also, I feel like instead of having `lastOf(Y, T2)`, you should have `T2` instead of `Y` in the head. But this is just a guess, until you provide us with `lastOf/2` to inspect.